# How can I restrict the use of OpenFrameworks to a single view controller in a native iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, openframeworks

I have an existing iOS (Swift- and storyboard-based) app and I'd like to use cross-platform OpenFrameworks code in just one `UIViewController`. However, I notice that the demo OF projects take over the iOS application lifecycle up to the application delegate class and even contain a customised `main.mm` file. Has anyone managed to create a storyboards-based iOS project where use of OF is restricted to a single view controller?

Comment: what is your question? the one in the title (how to contain it) or the one in the body text (on how to make it work with swift)

Comment: How to contain it within one view controller in an app that is Swift-based.

Comment: I think what OP is asking is how to use an OF view controller without adding all of the AppDelegate code from the OF demo. For that, we'd need to see the actual code.